# How to create a video chat in a ASP NET Web project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, webrtc, stun, videochat

I want to develop a video chat in my ASP Net Web Project and I would appreciate a piece of advice on how to implement it

### How I imagine it to work

A user clicks a button open video chat and he is redirected to a page, where the chat can happen.

So when he is redirected he is asked for permission to use mic and video and waits for someone to join. When he sends the same URL where he is located and someone joins the video chat starts.

### What am I using

- ASP.NET Web project - .NET Framework 4.8
- SignalR
- JavaScript

### What I've researched

I've seen WebRTC demo with SignalR and to be more specific this article: [Click](https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Skyline-Blog/February-2013/Peer-to-Peer-Media-Streaming-with-WebRTC-and-Signa)

The only problem with this article is that it seems that WebRTC is using STUN/TURN servers.  I am not familiar with how to create one and if there are public ones to use, like a google one.

```js
const configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: [
        'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
        'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
      ],
    },
  ],
  iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
};
```

I have seen those ones in a couple of GitHub projects, but recent posts claim that they are not working anymore.

### What is exactly my question?

- I would like to ask, if I am heading in the right direction with WebRTC and SignalR or if there is an option I don't know about, which implementation is more native for .NET.
- TURN/STUN servers? Is this the only problem with using WebRTC?
- Are there some examples?